# How do I cancel my Amazon Kindle free trial for this book?

Tags: amazon, kindle

I tried the eTextbook version of this book for free: [https://www.amazon.com/Krugmans-Economics-AP-Margaret-Ray-ebook/dp/B00HQO0CNS/ref=mt_kindle?_encoding=UTF8&me=](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B00HQO0CNS)

How do I end my free trial? Will it automatically cancel at the end of the 7-day period, or do I need to manually cancel it so I'm not automatically billed?

Comment: Anecdotally, I have done 3-4 of these and have never gotten a bill, but that could have changed in the intervening time, so it's not really an answer.